# Proving that the set of rational numbers in the interval [0, 2] is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $S$ be the set of rational numbers in the interval [0, 2]. Using the definition of compactness, show that $S$ is not compact.

It's trivial to show that $S$ is not compact by showing that it's not sequentially compact but I'm curious to see how anyone would prove that $S$ is not compact only by using coverings.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: It's pretty easy to show that $S \neq \phi$...

Comment: @GitGud: E.g. $0$ and $2$ are rational numbers included in $S$. There are plenty.

Comment: $1 \ \in \ \mathbb{Q}, 0 < 1 < 2$ so $1 \in S$

Comment: I forgot, the rationals aren't dense in $\mathbb{R}$; what was I thinking?

Comment: @Decave I misread the question.

Comment: @Decave: The rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GitGud I figured ;-)

Comment: @ThomasE. that was sarcasm, haha.

Comment: @Decave I see that now :)

Comment: @DonAntonio It was all in good fun. You know, math humor.

Comment: I'm sure it was, @Decave...:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take the covering given by sets:  $(-\infty,\sqrt 2-(1/n))$ and $(\sqrt 2+(1/n), +\infty)$. No subcover will contain all $S$ because any finite subcover will leave empty an interval near $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Which follows from the sequential density of the rationals -- I see. Thanks for your help, Mr. Paolini.

Answer (score 10):

Take $U_0= \mathbb{Q} \cap (\sqrt{2},2]$ and $U_n= \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,x_n)$ for $x_n \to \sqrt{2}$ an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Compact metric spaces are complete.  It is easy to find a cauchy sequence of rationals that fails to converge (in the rationals).

Here is another reason, related to that laid out by Emmanuele Paolini.  In a compact space, any nested sequence of decreasing nonvoid closed sets has nonvoid intersection.  Now consider
$$E_n = [\sqrt{2} - 1/n, \sqrt{2} + 1/n]\cap \mathbb{Q}, \qquad n\ge 4.$$